# How can I find all MP3 files in a directory?

Tags: delphi, glob, delphi-6

I recently started with delphi and now I want to get all mp3 files from a directory. I want something like the php function glob().

Comment: If you just recently started with Delphi, why are you on Delphi 6?

Comment: @Mason - Agreed!  It's not like Harry Potter, you don't have to start way back at the beginning!

Comment: @Mason Wheeler: because he had a copy lying around, and didn't want to spend 900 Euro's to search for mp3's?

Comment: @mason this is the version we have at school... Our service desk (system managers) are a bit slow...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The old way of doing it is approx:

```
var
  status : dword;
  sr : TSearchRec;
begin
  status := FindFirst('*.mp3',faAnyFile,sr);
  while status = 0 do
  begin

     // sr.Name is the filename; add it to a list
     // or something. Note there is no path so you
     // may need to add that back on somewhere

     status := FindNext(sr);
  end;
  SysUtils.FindClose(sr);

  // ...
end;
```

Comment: Works well, except while condition should be `status = 0`.

Answer (score 3):

Try IOUtils.TDirectory.

Comment: This type doesn't exist in Delphi 6.

Comment: Then use FindFirst etc. as suggested by Bill99 - that's how TDirectory is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

If additional libraries are ok for you, take a look at the Jedi Code Library.

In unit common\JclFileUtils, there is a compact helper function:

```
function BuildFileList(const Path: string; 
  const Attr: Integer; const List: TStrings; 
  IncludeDirectoryName: Boolean = False): Boolean;
```

The JCL is well maintained and includes great extensions and some IDE improvements. The (very easy to use) JCL installer is available at http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/

Answer (score 1):

The ancient [TFileListBox](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/FileCtrl.TFileListBox) in the Delphi [FileCtrl](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/FileCtrl) unit is a good solution.

It has been there since Delphi 1, and About Delphi [has a nice example on how to use it](http://delphi.about.com/od/vclusing/a/filecontrols.htm).

You can drop it on a form, set `Visible = False`, and never worry about it.

It supports filtering (for instance on extension), so it will work very nicely with your *.mp3 criterion.

--jeroen

Answer (score 0):

a very nice free component is TFindFile at Delphi Area:
http://www.delphiarea.com/products/delphi-components/findfile/

it will give you complete control over searching for files/folders, threaded or non